# How to get a String from an xml file when using an object in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: xml, string, kotlin, object, android-jetpack-compose

Instead of direcly write "red", "yellow" and "green", I would like to get the string from xml.

```
object Apples {
    val apples = listOf("red", "yellow", "green"
    )
}
```

I have tried
`val context = LocalContext.current`
but it is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to access context inside `object`.
I suggest you, instead of writing colors directly, use something like this:

```kotlin
object Apples {
    val apples = listOf<Int>(
        R.string.red,
        R.string.yellow,
        R.string.green,
    )
}
```

This way, when you need to output any of the values, you simply call `stringResource(apples[0])`.

That being said, I might (depending on the use case) solve this by using `enum`:

```kotlin
enum class Apples(val nameResId: Int) {
    Red(R.string.red),
    Yellow(R.string.yellow),
    Green(R.string.green)
}
```

The actual presentation of the string should not be baked into the object itself, but rather the UI should take care of it. While you probably could make a `@Composable` function inside the `object`, you will create another composable function you won't be able to use outside composable functions.

Comment: Thanks for your information. I think your advice will also help me to resolve my problem

Answer (score 1):

Define your strings in res/values/strings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="apple_red">red</string>
    <string name="apple_yellow">yellow</string>
    <string name="apple_green">green</string>
</resources>
```

then.

```
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.res.stringResource
import com.example.yourapp.R

object Apples {
    @Composable
    fun getAppleColors(): List<String> {
        return listOf(
            stringResource(R.string.apple_red),
            stringResource(R.string.apple_yellow),
            stringResource(R.string.apple_green)
        )
    }
}

@Composable
fun AppleList() {
    val apples = Apples.getAppleColors()
    // Use 'apples' list in your Composable, it now contains the strings from XML.
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will use that way to resolve my proble then.